# Issue using nested routes in React-Router with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, react-router, url-routing

I have done some googling, but to no avail on this issue. Currently I have the following setup with React-Router

```
Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation, function(Handler) {
  React.render(<Handler />, document.getElementById('app'));
});


export default (
  <Route path="/" handler={App}>
    <Route path="" handler={Home} />
    <Route path="create-job" handler={CreateJob} />
    <Route path="jobs" handler={JobStatuses} />
    <Route path="job/:jobId" handler={Job} />
  </Route>
);
```

I also have the following `webpack.config.js` file.

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'app', 'main.js')
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'static'),
        publicPath: "static/",
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: path.join(__dirname, 'app'), loaders: ["react-hot", "babel?stage=0"] },
            { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff" },
            { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|png)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader" }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        // Avoid publishing files when compilation failed
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
    ],
    stats: {
        // Nice colored output
        colors: true
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        proxy: { "\/api\/*": "http://localhost:8888" }
    },
    // Create Sourcemaps for the bundle
    devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Project Hippo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="./static/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now when I go to a url with the following for `http:localhost:8080/job/0001` I get a 404 error for not being able to locate `http:localhost:8080/job/static/bundle.js`

I feel that I am just missing something fairly simple.

As a side not, this is entirely client side routing.

Answer (score 16):

It will be nice to know your directory structure.

From your `webpack.config.js` publicPath, your javascript files are being bundled into `http://localhost:8080/static/bundle.js`

But you have set a relative path (`./static/bundle.js`) in your index.html file.

This is why when you visit `http://localhost:8080/jobs/0001` your browser tries to look for your bundle.js in `http://localhost:8080/jobs/static/bundle.js`.

So set your script source in your index.html to use an absolute path, i.e.

`<script src="/static/bundle.js"></script>`

You should be fine.

Answer (score 5):

This is due to your `publicPath` being **relative**. Change your public path to be absolute like so:

```
output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'static'),
            publicPath: "/static/",
            filename: 'bundle.js'
},
```