# subdirs in url breaks react route with custom webpack setup

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

I have a simple UI where I display a list of objects and then a form to add one.
The default page shows the list of objects with a menu to add a new one. When I click on the new link, I get a 404

[image: default]

When I click on `New Company` I get a blank screen and a 404 because it cannot find the `main.js`

[image: new_company]

Wondering what the hell is `main.js` I was looking through my code and see I have it defined in my webpack config;

```
module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
        filename: "main.js"
    },
    target: "node",
    devServer: {
        port: "9000",
        contentBase: ["./public"],
        open: true,
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".json"]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                include: /src/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
                    },
                    'css-loader',
                    'postcss-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "styles.css"
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "public/index.html" //source html
        }),
    ]
}
```

I thought I had my webpack setup correctly but I think I must be missing something?

Running more tests I added a simple about page that just displayed a heading and had it at `/about`

```
const CompanyBox = () => (
  <>
    <Menu/>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <CompanyList/>
      </Route>
      <Route exact path="/companies/new">
        <CompanyForm/>
      </Route>
      <Route path="/companies/:companyId">
        <CompanyDetails/>
      </Route>
      <RolesRoute path="/secret" roles={['admin']}>
        <SecretCompanies/>
      </RolesRoute>
      <Route path="/about">
        <About />
      </Route>
      <Route path="*">
        <NoMatch/>
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </>
)

function About() {
  return (
      <div>
        <h2>About</h2>
      </div>
  );
}
```

I also added it to the links in the menu. When I go to the URL directly or via the link it both works

[image: about]

But when I change the url to something like `/about/new`, I get the error on the console that it can't find the `main.js`

[image: no_about]

Not sure why the routes doesn't work when I go 2 levels deep in the url directories

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33041954/issue-using-nested-routes-in-react-router-with-webpack).
I knew it was a webpack config issue, but turns out I had the path to the html file set relatively and not absolute